# How to recheck required input fields in JavaScript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to stay away from JQuery for this one (nothing against JQuery, I just don't want to load a huge library into this project for something small like this).

I'm curious how I might tell HTML5 to recheck all the required input fields in a given form. For example, I have this form (albeit slightly more complicated but you get the point):

```
<form action="here" onsubmit="check()">
    <input required name="something">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I don't have anything in that required field, HTML5 shows a popup error, something to the effect of "Please fill in this required field". What is stopping the user from putting in a single space, or some nonsense character like `%` or `>`? I'd like to partially validate this client-side (in addition to server side) so it isn't particularly inconvenient when the page redirects to the form submission page and then shows the error, and then goes back to the form, prompting the user to enter everything over again.

Assuming in my onsubmit function `check` I've removed all whitespace and/or nonsense characters from the ends of the string, how can that function then tell HTML5 to recheck the form to see if the required fields are still not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `onsubmit="check()"` use  `addEventListener`.
Now you can do everything with input data.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var something = document.getElementById("something").value;
  document.getElementById("something").value = something.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "");
});
```

```html
<form action="here">
    <input required name="something" id="something">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So will HTML5 still show the little popup notification if the newly-modified field is blank?

Comment: Yes, you can check it. Click `Run code snippet`. Enter some spaces and special characters. It will show that error box.

Comment: Also, you can edit regex in js function to specify what you need.

Answer (score 1):

try to use regexp pattern (e.g. exclude white chars: `[^\s]*`, allow only letters `[A-Za-z]*`, ...)

```html
<form action="here" onsubmit="check()">
    <input required pattern="[^\s]*" name="something" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting solution! So what regex would you suggest to make sure the input isn't some amount of spaces or tabs, for example? I'm not very good with regex.

Comment: @JadenBaptista I update answer - `\s` means white char `*` means any number

Comment: I can still use special characters. Your solution not working

Comment: It also isn't removing the whitespace like I asked, but that's no matter. This is the answer to a similar and related question, so it still fits here, I just marked the other answer correct. Thanks!